# Not able to map from String representation of a POJO to another POJO using model mapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

Say I have a String or JSON representation of a class as:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "address":{
     "street":"Baker",
     "city":"London"
    }
}
```

& I want to map this JSON to a POJO which I have as following:

```
public class OrderDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private Address orderAddress;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Address getOrderAddress() {
        return orderAddress;
    }

    public void setOrderAddress(Address orderAddress) {
        this.orderAddress = orderAddress;
    }
}
```

I am using ModelMapper for doing this and using `PropertyMap<JsonElement,OrderDTO>` to write the mapping for the property which is different in the POJO from the JSON. The implementation is as:

```
PropertyMap<JsonElement,OrderDTO>orderMap = new PropertyMap<JsonElement, OrderDTO>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        map().setOrderAddress(this.<Address>source("address"));
    }
};
```

However, while executing I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) The source path address is invalid: com.google.gson.JsonObject.address cannot be resolved.

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwConfigurationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:241)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:244)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapImpl.addMappings(TypeMapImpl.java:92)
```

I am not finding any resource which I can refer to for mapping from String/JSON type to POJO. What could be the issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using Jackson or Gson?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, there will be cases where field names in the DTO will change and hence while serializing from the JSON to the new DTO I will need to map the old field name present in the JSON to the new field name present in the DTO. 
Note: I cannot add annotations like @JsonProperty to the DTO since I will be receiving this DTO as a part of library.

For example: the field for order ID was `id` in Order POJO while serializing, but while de-serializing we have an updated POJO of Order where that field name gets changed to say `orderId`.

Comment: That's exactly the reason Jackson mixins exist.